# How to get numbers into array after point "."

Tags: c++

How i can put the numbers into array like `11*11 = 121` how i can put 121 as `1,2,1` into array , so that it should like `int arr[] = [1,2,1];` , the one logic to me is divide it by `10` , the code i am trying is

```
    long mul , cube;
    mul = num*num;
    cube = num*num*num;
    float unt = mul/10.0;
```

But how to save the number after period `.` into array , like if i have the number `2.3` so i want to save `3` into array

Comment: Please try to phrase your answer in understandable english. It is really hard to follow your reasoning...

Comment: Sometimes I wonder how people can come up with such nonsensical sentences...

Comment: @Quentin: It's a gift... or incessant practice.

Comment: The only period is in the code :(

Comment: If you want to compare two numbers, which seems to be the case from your question, why not store them as whole integers or decimals in the array instead of as individual digits ? Like `int a[] = 121` instead of `int a = {1,2,1}`.

Comment: @Vivek S If we can compare it like that ?

Comment: @gexicide Which answer ?

Comment: @AHF: Sorry, question!

Comment: @gexicide sorry brother , no one here belong from pure english community , i think it can easily be understandable as a native speaker

Comment: Are you asking about the modulus operator in C++? The modulus operator being `%`, i.e. `91 % 10 = 1`?

Comment: but what about when we got num like `1234443`?

Comment: @AHF, are you looking for a code sample or just an algorithm?

Comment: Code sample as just the starter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to get the individual digits into an array.

You can get the digits into an array in reverse order by following the algorithm (let n be the number you want to split):

```
while (n > 0):
   push (n mod 10) into the array --- this is one digit from 0..9
   divide n by 10, ignoring the decimal part (ignoring remainder, that is)
```

For example, with n=97 you get:

```
(n mod 10) = 7, push that into array
divide 97 by 10 to get 9 (ignoring .7)
(n mod 10) = 9, push that into array
divide 9 by 10 to get 0
end algorithm
```

now you have [7, 9] in the array, then reverse the array to get the left-to-right ordering.

Answer (score 2):

Follow on from the OP requesting a code sample, and my understanding of the question. This implements the algorithm from another answer (Antti Huima);

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<int> convert(int number)
{
    std::vector<int> result;

    if (number == 0) {
        result.push_back(0);
    }

    while (number) {
        int temp = number % 10;
        number /= 10;
        result.push_back(temp);
        //result.insert(result.begin(), temp); // alternative... inserts in "forward" order
    }

    // push_back inserts the elements in reverse order, so we reverse them again
    std::reverse(result.begin(), result.end());

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 123;
    auto result = convert(i);
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
    for (auto& j : result) {
        std::cout << j << ',';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

It's been implemented assuming certain basics (that can be altered or templated);

- `int` base type and `int` as the array member
- Variable array size is catered for (in the `vector`)
- `convert` is a very arbitrary name
- The `main` is just a demonstration of its use (so I was a little more liberal in C++11 language use).

[Live code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e469c3ee787a2612)